# Type Script Class Input Interface with optional params

Tags: typescript

So I'm fighting the compiler here a bit and wanted to see where I'm going wrong or if I'm just chasing an anti-pattern and should change the approach.

What I would like is to be able to have a class with required parameters, and an input `interface` with optional parameters. If the `Input` doesn't have a given parameter the class constructor computes a sensible default.

```js
interface PersonInput {
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
}

class Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  constructor(input: PersonInput) {
    this.name = "Zach";
    this.age = 30;
    for (const key in input) {
      this[key] = input[key]; // <--- Errors here with 
    }
  }
}
// test.ts:13:19 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because 
// expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'PersonInput'.
```

Okay that's fine what if I assert that the element will not have an `any` type associated with it.

```js
\\ ...snip
    for (const key in input) {
      const personParam: keyof Person = key; // <-- Type 'string | number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'
      this[personParam] = input[personParam];
    }
\\...snip
```

So in my case I just avoided the `spread` of properties and did something like this:

```js
//...snip
class Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  constructor(input: PersonInput) {
    this.name = input.name || "Zach";
    this.age = input.age || 30;
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Addendum

I've also been reading about the `param!` syntax is that needed for this case? I wouldn't think so because the loop will only run with that parameter if it has been defined, its never dependent on a property being passed in the `input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this without the need to write all assignments manually and then keep them in sync when you add new properties to the class is to just assign the default values when you declare the properties and then use `Object.assign(target, source)` inside the constructor.

Also if your interface is just your original type `Person` with all properties being optional, then Typescript has a helper type called `Partial<T>` that you can use. So instead of declaring an additional interface `PersonInput` (that you need to keep in sync with `Person`) you can just use `Partial<Person>` as the type anywhere you need it.

So all the suggestion above put together give us

```js
class Person {
  name: string = "Zach";
  age: number = 30;

  constructor(input: Partial<Person>) {
    Object.assign(this, input);
  }
}
```

But if you want to keep your `for` loop approach, you just need to tell a few more things to the compiler so that it lets you do what you want.

```
class Person {
  name: string = "Zach";
  age: number = 30;
  constructor(input: Partial<Person>) { // or keep your PersonInput type
    for (const key in input) {
      // instead of just declaring the type you have to do a cast
      const personParam = key as keyof Person; 
      // shortest way to make the compiler let you index a type that it 
      // would not let you index otherwise (and you know it is safe to index)
      // is to use 'as any'
      (this as any)[personParam] = input[personParam];
    }
  }
}
```

Note that these solutions will set a property to `undefined` if `undefined` is actually passed as a value for any of the properties, like this `new Person({ name: undefined })` or `new Person({ age: undefined })` or `new Person({ name: undefined, age: undefined })`.

So `new Person({})` is not the same as `new Person({ name: undefined, age: undefined })`.

Run the above code in the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gWAFDWjTAFt4AuaCAF0QEs0BzaAXmgCIAtMYACzYG48BMA3KEArsQBGSFtADMABkH5oQ6MHTVE44FRSIAFPQAO4qhVhhEVWmBAAeBMnQA+AJRZ1BAPJSAVvB6AHSQELQMaIZUPLQQADTQpubu6gC+eBm4eKBhcEioaABMXqpEpBTa9EysnNx8KsKiFGiSMohySo0aWjS6+kbJFnDWtvZOBW6eOKoEAGYG0IaaaNTQANbwAJ5JGEPT3gQ9q1TQJpNoVogkcps7kBvbKHP5LmjdR9AA9F+UPAZUeBrADuYB2+mgxDAm2gMXgPWIJloIFkKNOWxQ4l2ABN4AAPaBgWFbc6wnhgU60U6HAg-aDAzEgbGEFCnNHQDFY+i4gmsnhIYFxeGGMBoZmcjZoFDApKUmAQMBzeEQ7n41KzI50uKwlDQcQQeEAcgeoq2hppSxi2pNaC27gA2uc3lcSABdORDR0XF3EV0faBZAhZLJ4e2HNDwGXOQqGTAB9zxcOR16FIqx+OJjURqMXdPlMSGgByrOgXF4hozSZzbzTcfzFCLJbLPAraQTVZT6HTIjERUUlazyej6FrhOa0D7A8+2c7UTjPYo4jF8Dm9HgzLbmenQ4uo4XeuXq4jG-bGrpM+Hc8oKFIPjhiFgiBQJgok8331+AFEAErfnzfw5zx3Gt01QW970fZ9X37d86R-P8ANwV1ggWRBP3qYxTmYVxjlQFFghAFAGEw9x3CAA)

Comment: Thats super helpful, appreciate the walkthough. I'm curious if you can use the `Object.assign` when it potentially has a property that doesn't belong to the class and if that throughs an error at compile time. I'll test it out.

Comment: @Gates You can do what you ask and it won't throw an error at compile time, but in your case the compiler will make sure that you can only call the `Person` constructor with a `Partial<Person>`. But in general, when using `Object.assign` on its own, it will accept anything, and its signature is `Object.assign<T, U>(target: T, source: U): T & U`, so its return type is `T & U`, which means the union of both types of the values that were passed in. In your case, the union is `Person & Partial<Person>`, thus the extra note at the end of my answer about the behavior with `undefined` values.